# Applying a Storyboard when a item changed using ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm refactoring a WPF application that before was using a `ObservableCollection<T>` as datasource with a `ListCollectionView` for performance purpose.

The main idea is that I've a `ItemHolder` which has a `ObservableCollection<T>` that contains all the data and each view of my application shows only a part of it (based on an `IdParent`).In this case `ListCollectionView` works fine since I set a filter on the `ItemHolder.Items` and I get the data.

I wish to execute a storyboard when a record is updated inside this collection (adding an item works since I see it on the `GridView`).

Is there a way I can get a storyboard applied when a item is changed? I've seen no `SourceCollectionChanged` (or something similar) as event of the `ListCollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with `ListCollectionView` before so I cannot tell you anything new. But I can suggest to create a custom control that inherits from `ListCollectionView` and then implement an CollectionChanged event to handle when an item is added to the custom control and trigger the animation from withing the user control.